# Is $\mathbb{Q}$ an ordered field?

Tags: real-analysis

Is $\mathbb{Q}$ an ordered field? Why or why not? We're discussing ordered fields in my real analysis course an my buddy and I are disagreeing as to whether or not $\mathbb{Q}$ fits the classification of an ordered field.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah. An ordered field is a field with an order that guarantees that (1) positive ($>0$) times positive equals positive and (2) addition is order-preserving ($m+p>n+p$ if $m>n$). That's clearly true of $\mathbb Q$ with the usual order: you learned that at age eight or so.

Answer (score 2):

Every subfield of an ordered field is an ordered field with the same ordering as the original one. Since $\mathbb Q \le \mathbb R$, it is an ordered field. The same holds true, for example, for the field $\mathbb Q[\sqrt{2}] \le \mathbb R$ as well.

Comment: Note that there is only one order possible for $\mathbb Q$, but there are two for $\mathbb Q[\sqrt 2]$